# Retrieve custom URL segment with CI

Tags: class, url, codeigniter, helper

I looked at the URL helper and URI class and I noticed that both of these work off the URL in the address bar. Is there a way I can use this helper or class with my own URL string? I want to retrieve the last segment of a URL I give and I don't want to resort to `preg_match` unless I need to. Is there a way to do this with codeigniter functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a string in the format of **http://example.com/foo/bar** (I presume that's what you mean by 'own URL string'?), you should be able to just do something like this:

```
$url = "http://example.com/foo/bar";
$parts = explode("/", $url);
$last = end($parts);  // => bar
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$this->uri->segment($this->uri->total_segments())
```

or

```
array_pop($this->uri->segment_array())
```

if you want to use CI functionality.